# Jolt transformation - Create a new collection

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

**I have this json on json input**

{
"$id": "11343",
"nomeRota": "2310 - 2401",
"placa": "PAN0001",
"nomeMotorista": "Motorista Padrão Bauducco",
"codigoMotorista": null,
"dataSaida": "2020-06-29T06:00:00-03:00",
"dataChegada": "2020-06-30T08:02:52.56-03:00",
"tipoVeiculo": "0001 - FIORINO  / P 600 / M 1,7 / PLT 0,5",
"codigoExternoVeiculo": null,
"documentoTransportadora": null,
"codigoTransportadora": null,
"custoFrete": 0,
"metrosDistanciaTotal": 2622105,
"metrosDistanciaRetorno": 875029,
"segundosRetorno": 46755,
"codigoRota": 2171526,
"numeroRota": 1,
"exportado": true,
"custoTotal": 0,
"atividades": [
{
"$id": "11344",
"codigoCliente": "15701",
"sequencia": 1,
"metrosDistanciaPercorrida": 872047,
"dataChegada": "2020-06-29T18:48:36.62-03:00",
"dataSaida": "2020-06-29T19:03:36.62-03:00",
"pedidos": [
{
"$id": "11345",
"numeroPedido": "123456789",
"unidade": null,
"peso": 5.41,
"capacidade": 0,
"dataPedido": "2020-06-28T00:00:00-03:00",
"itens": [
{
"$id": "11346",
"nomeProduto": "Produto (PROD-123456-A)",
"identificadorProduto": "PROD-123456-A",
"nomeTipoProduto": null,
"identificadorTipoProduto": null,
"tamanho": 0,
"peso": 0.56,
"sequencia": "",
"valor": 0,
"quantidade": 4
},
{
"$id": "11347",
"nomeProduto": "Produto (PROD-123456-B)",
"identificadorProduto": "PROD-123456-B",
"nomeTipoProduto": null,
"identificadorTipoProduto": null,
"tamanho": 0,
"peso": 4.85,
"sequencia": "",
"valor": 0,
"quantidade": 7
}
]
}
]
},
{
"$id": "11344",
"codigoCliente": "88888",
"sequencia": 88,
"metrosDistanciaPercorrida": 872047,
"dataChegada": "2020-06-29T18:48:36.62-03:00",
"dataSaida": "2020-06-29T19:03:36.62-03:00",
"pedidos": [
{
"$id": "11345",
"numeroPedido": "88888888",
"unidade": null,
"peso": 5.41,
"capacidade": 0,
"dataPedido": "2020-06-28T00:00:00-03:00",
"itens": [
{
"$id": "11346",
"nomeProduto": "Produto (PROD-123456-A)",
"identificadorProduto": "PROD-123456-A",
"nomeTipoProduto": null,
"identificadorTipoProduto": null,
"tamanho": 0,
"peso": 0.56,
"sequencia": "",
"valor": 0,
"quantidade": 4
},
{
"$id": "11347",
"nomeProduto": "Produto (PROD-123456-B)",
"identificadorProduto": "PROD-123456-B",
"nomeTipoProduto": null,
"identificadorTipoProduto": null,
"tamanho": 0,
"peso": 4.85,
"sequencia": "",
"valor": 0,
"quantidade": 7
}
]
}
]
}
]
}

**and I need create this json collection**

{
"IDplaca" : "PAN0001",
"IDMotorista" : null,
"ListaDePedidosDaRota" : [ {
"Sequencia" : 1,
"ChaveDeFato" : "123456789",
}, {
"Sequencia" : 88
"ChaveDeFato" :"88888888"
} ]
}

**I am using this SPEC**

[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"placa": "IDplaca",
"codigoMotorista": "IDMotorista",
"atividades": {
"*": {
"sequencia": "ListaDePedidosDaRota[&1].Sequencia",
"pedidos": {
"*": {
"numeroPedido": "ListaDePedidosDaRota[&1].ChaveDeFato"
}
}
}
}
}
}
]

**but are creating this json, adding the value of the field in unique collection "ChaveDeFato"**

{
"IDplaca" : "PAN0001",
"IDMotorista" : null,
"ListaDePedidosDaRota" : [ {
"Sequencia" : 1,
**"ChaveDeFato" : [ "123456789", "88888888" ]**
}, {
"Sequencia" : 88
} ]
}

**how to make this SPEC for create the json spected?**

Answer (score 0):

This spec works,
sequencia should be shifted inside the pedidos array to get the desired output.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "placa": "IDplaca",
      "codigoMotorista": "IDMotorista",
      "atividades": {
        "*": {
          "pedidos": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,sequencia)": "ListaDePedidosDaRota[&3].Sequencia",
              "numeroPedido": "ListaDePedidosDaRota[&3].ChaveDeFato"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
```